# Python Break Statement

Tags: python, loops, break

I wrote this function to compare two fields from different data sets and it correctly returns the like data points as well as logs the amount of duplicates that are in the second column and percentage of entries in the first column that are found in the second.

My question is with regard to the break statement in the third for loop. It seems to me as if when it finds a duplicate it should just terminate that loop and continue on to the else statement and still append it to the same list.

However, it moves on to the next iteration of the first for loop as if it is breaking out of the two nested loops at the same time.

What is happening here? My best guess is that is has something to do with referring to "i" in the outer most loop.

```
def compare_fields(col1, col2):
    ticker = 0
    same=[]
    counter= 0
    total = 0
    duplicates = 0
    for i in col1:
        total +=1
        for x in col2:
            if i != x:
                continue
            for j in same:
                if j == i:
                    duplicates +=1
                    break    
            else:
                same.append(i) 
                counter+=1
    return same, counter, round(counter/total*100), duplicates
```

Comment: The `else` clause of a `for` loop only executes if the loop exits normally. It is specifically designed *not to run* when you `break` out of a loop. See also: [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: The `else` clause is connected to the `for` in the same way an `if/else` pair are connected. They are on the same level of indentation. With `for/else` the else only runs if the `for` completes without breaking.